# From where can I get Shiva Rahasya Purana's English translation?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, itihasa, ramana-maharshi

Also known as just Shiva Rahasya. This great scripture is also considered Shaiva Itihasa and contains Ribhu Gita which was quoted by Ramana Maharshi. I want to know where can I get full english translation of this scripture.

Comment: https://archive.org/download/ShriShivaRahasya/ShriShivaRahasya.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The Shiva Rahasya Purana english version can be read from [here.](https://www.astrojyoti.com/shivarahasyapurana.htm) If you wanna to download it, from [here](https://lib-iqeciqodwgcng4euvaqw6ab5.1lib.at/book/19317019/df2042) you can.

Comment: Is it complete unabridged translation?

Comment: @RishX yes it is

Comment: No original contains over 100,000 shlokas